# Minimum number $s$ such that all the unions of $s$ of the $p$ subsets are equal

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, reference-request

I'm asking for references in literature on the following problem.

Given a positive integer $n$, $S=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $p$ distinct subsets of $S$, $A_1,\dots,A_p$, what is the minimum number $s>0$ such that
$$
\bigcup_{i\in L}A_i=\bigcup_{j\in M}A_j
$$
for all subsets $L,M\subseteq S$ of size $s$.

Clearly, if the sets $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint the number $s$ is $p$. Is it possible to determine the integer $s$ a priori, or to find upper and/or lower bounds for $s$.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean, the minimum number $s\gt0$, otherwise $s=0$ is your answer.

Comment: You could ask the same question more simply: what is the minimum number $s$ such that $$\bigcup_{i\in L}A_i=\bigcup_{i\in S}A_i$$ for all subsets $L\subseteq S$ of size $s$.

Comment: Don't you mean to say $L,M\subseteq \{1,\dots,p\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal $s$ is $\min(p,2^{n-1}+1)$.

You know that $s=p$ will always work. Similarly, $s=2^{n-1}+1$ will work, because $|L|=2^{n-1}+1$ implies $\bigcup_{i\in L} A_i=\{1,\dots,n\}$. Indeed, $\bigcup_{i\in L} A_i$ cannot be missing any element $i$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, because there are only $2^{n-1}$ subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ which are missing $i$.

To see this is optimal, suppose $s<\min(p,2^{n-1}+1)$. Choose the sets $A_1,\dots,A_p$ such that

- $A_1=\{1\}$,
- $1\notin A_i$ for $i\in \{2,3,\dots,\min(p,2^{n-1}+1)\}$.

With this setup, if $L$ contains $1$, then $\bigcup_{i\in L}A_i$ will contain $1$, but if $L\subseteq \{2,3,\dots,\min(p,2^{n-1}+1)\}$, then $\bigcup_{i\in L}A_i$ will not contain $1$. Therefore, $\bigcup_{i\in L}A_i$ is not always the same.